# Django URL appending hash

Tags: python, django

Hi All i have a small test app that has a basic model with a form based on this model:

```
class PublicNotesPost(models.Model):
    noteName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    termsAgreed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    noteData = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Test Note Post Data"
```

My aim is when i post a note it redirects to a viewer with a dynamic url, at the moment i have not setup the viewer just an empty html file with a H1 tag just to test redirection. However what happens is a Hash is appended to the end of the url and i cant for the life of me figure out why this is and wanted to post here in case anyone has experienced this and has an understanding of how to rectify it?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/note/ryXVe7tAhC/#
```

My Url patterns are as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('note/composer/', views.NoteComposer.as_view() ,name="note_composer"),
    path('note/<str:shorturl>/', views.ViewNote ,name="noteviewer")
]
```

View functions:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import PostComposerForm
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View
import string
import random

# Create your views here.

def short_random_string(N:int) -> str:
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase +string.ascii_lowercase+ string.digits) for i in range(N))


class NoteComposer(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            formdata = {
                'form': PostComposerForm(),
                'navbar_active': 'composer',
                'agreedTerms': False
            }
            return render(request, 'main/composer.html', formdata)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            return redirect('/')

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            form = PublicComposerForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                shortUrl = short_random_string(10)
                return redirect(reverse('noteviewer', kwargs={"shorturl": shortUrl}))
            pass

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            return redirect('/')



def ViewNote(request, shorturl):
    try:
        return render(request,'main/view_note.html')
    except:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Nothing you've shown here would cause the hash to be shown, do you have any 3rd party packages?

Comment: On a different note (nothing to do with the # problem): I see you're catching all exceptions in all your views and redirecting to home if that happens. Don't do that! It's very bad practice. You **should** leave exceptions uncaught and let them return a 500 error page. Otherwise you're making debugging impossible. And users don't expect to just jump to the home page without warning.

Comment: @dirkgroten I am testing at the moment so not live and won't be there in the end its purely there while it debug i just cant figure out this darn url append of hash symbol follows browser so looking to see if any js is a root cause?

Comment: In development it's even worse because you can never catch your bugs this way. Anyway, a hash is used to link to anchors on your page, e.g. `/note/490w94/#title` would link to a div with id title. The hash on its own links to the top of the page. So it seems some js is causing this. Show us `view_note.html` in its entirety.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok seems this was definitely something in the html which was the form action.

as i was testing the form action merely had # and this was being passed into the function and thus appended to the url :
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
Removing the hash cured this issue - feeling a tad silly now ;)